# When to use parenthesis and when not to use parenthesis while assigning variables in VB6?

Tags: vb6

I am looking at some old VB6 code. I am new to VB and I come from a C/Java background, so I don't understand some of the assignment statements. Here is one example -

```
     Private Type UGH
       Rsp(3) As Byte
       ProgramId(7) As Byte
       RID(7) As Byte
       TID(3) As Byte
       FL(39) As Byte
    End Type
    Private UHeader As UGH
```

Later, the assignment takes place as follows-

```
    With UHeader
    StringToByteArray UHeader.ProgramId(), "ABCDPQRS"
```

My question is, why is the parenthesis used after ProgramId in the above assignment? To me it seems like a function call, but it obviously is not a function call. Then what is it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well it is not actually needed. Calling the same line without the parenthesis will do exactly the same thing. The reason it is allowed is because it is a byte array.

Maybe rewriting the line like this will make it more readable:

```
call StringToByteArray(UHeader.ProgramId(), "ABCDPQRS")
```

But this is also valid:

```
call StringToByteArray(UHeader.ProgramId, "ABCDPQRS")
```

It would probably make more sense to you if the StringToByteArray method was a function instead of a subroutine:

```
Private Function StringToByteArray(ByVal strValue As String) As Byte()
    'conversion code left out
End Function
```

Then you can call it like this:

```
UHeader.ProgramId() = StringToByteArray("ABCDPQRS")
```

or this:

```
UHeader.ProgramId = StringToByteArray("ABCDPQRS")
```

Answer (score 1):

The parenthesis in this case is used to designate an array.  For `Rsp(3) as Byte`, it indicates an array of 3 bytes indexed from 0 to 2.

For the line: `StringToByteArray UHeader.ProgramId(), "ABCDPQRS", StringToByteArray` is a method that takes a byte array--when passing an array to a method, you pass it in as `array()`.

Comment: `Rsp` is probably 4 bytes -- 0 to 3 (incl.)

Answer (score 0):

Parenthesis are also used for array syntax.

And so it's said, `StringToByteArray UHeader.ProgramId(), "ABCDPQRS"` is not strictly an assignment, it is a method (subroutine or function) call.  `StringToByteArray` is going to be defined somewhere in your program and it will probably take a ByRef array parameter, a string parameter, and it probably copys the string parameter into the the byte buffer.

Answer (score 0):

UHeader.ProgramId is actually a pointer to the array.  You can simply do this: `StringToByteArray UHeader.ProgramID, "ABCDPQRS"`.  The rule in VB6 is that Functions require parenthesization of argument lists and Subs require non-parenthesization, unless preceded by the Call statement in which case they do.

Since you are passing the array by reference (the default), operations performed in the subroutine are performed on the array itself.  Basically, you are passing a pointer to an array and a literal string, and the subroutine will populate the array with the characters in the string.  Sort of like an "informal" function call, if you will.